# Не могу подключится к серверу сокетов на локалке

Tags: php, websocket, localhost

Система - Mac OS Mojave

Хочу сделать обмен сообщениями через сокеты. Использую вот такой код для сервера

```
<?php
require_once '../../vendor/autoload.php';
use Workerman\Worker;

// массив для связи соединения пользователя и необходимого нам параметра
$users = [];

// создаём ws-сервер, к которому будут подключаться все наши пользователи
$ws_worker = new Worker("websocket://0.0.0.0:7200");
// создаём обработчик, который будет выполняться при запуске ws-сервера
$ws_worker->onWorkerStart = function() use (&$users)
{
    // создаём локальный tcp-сервер, чтобы отправлять на него сообщения из кода нашего сайта
    $inner_tcp_worker = new Worker("tcp://127.0.0.1:7100");
    // создаём обработчик сообщений, который будет срабатывать,
    // когда на локальный tcp-сокет приходит сообщение
    $inner_tcp_worker->onMessage = function($connection, $data) use (&$users) {
        $data = json_decode($data);
        foreach ($users as $user){
            $webconnection = $user;
            $webconnection->send($data->message);
        }
    };
    $inner_tcp_worker->listen();
};

$ws_worker->onConnect = function($connection) use (&$users)
{
    $connection->onWebSocketConnect = function($connection) use (&$users)
    {
        // при подключении нового пользователя сохраняем get-параметр, который же сами и передали со страницы сайта
        $users[$_GET['uid']] = $connection;
        // вместо get-параметра можно также использовать параметр из cookie, например $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']
        echo 'Подключение нового пользователя '.$_GET['uid']."\n";
    };
};

$ws_worker->onMessage = function($connection, $data) use (&$users)
{
    $data = json_decode($data);
    echo $data->user."\n";
    // Send hello $data
    if (isset($users[$data->user])) {
        echo "Попытка отправить сообщение пользователю ".$data->user."\n";
        $webconnection = $users[$data->user];
        $webconnection->send(json_encode($data));
    }
};


$ws_worker->onClose = function($connection) use(&$users)
{
    // удаляем параметр при отключении пользователя
    $user = array_search($connection, $users);
    unset($users[$user]);
};

// Run worker
Worker::runAll();
```

Сервер запускается и работает - http://joxi.ru/52al0K4HE3407m

Пробую подключится к нему

```
let ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:7200/?uid=$uid')
ws.onopen = function () {
    console.log('App connect to server')
}
```

Получаю ошибку

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:7200/?uid=test' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
```

Может кто сталкивался, помогите пожалуйста решить эту проблему

P.S. На сервере использую такой же код и все работает, а вот на локалке не хочет

Comment: Посмотрите занят порт 7200 чем-то, или нет

Answer (score 1):

Все проблема была в том, что у меня была версия php 7.3. Она, как я понял, не стабильная (или код не подходил этой версии). Я понизил до 7.2 и все прекрасно работает. Всем спасибо